# SOA, retrieve DTO from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, architecture, soa

I want to use SOA environment for my project. I have a several requirements:
1. Web site on `Asp.Net MVC 4`
2. CMS for the site - on `Asp.Net MVC` or `Silverlight`.
3. The mobile applications - `iOS, Android, WP`
4. Also, there are must be `API` for external services (pay terminal, web sites and other, mobile apps also can use this API)

Therefore, I want to use `SOA`. And I have one question.

The services coordinates the interaction between business objects and data access 
objects by saving and retrieving business objects using `DAOs` (data access objects) to 
and from the database. And, I must to convert entities to `DTO` and vice versa. I can use `Autommaper` for this, for example. But, I worry about performance.

For example, we have method in repository which return info about order. The `Order` have many `FK` to other tables. But, I need to only two tables. A generated sql contain many `join` for all references tables.  Then we convert this order entity to DTO.

The question: how to or What I need to use for generating query that it will be lightweight and contains fields only needed for `DTO`? I must to use `ExpressionTrees` or something else, there are some examples or library?

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need an ORM tool.
http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/ is good. If you want to stay with .NET you could use Entity Framework (but I'm not an expert in it).